# I think I rinsed my nose more than three times during ghusl

Tags: ghusl

I was performing ghusl; rinsing my nose but when I was about to wash my face I was in doubt if I really rinsed my nose three times so I did it one time more to be sure.

I hope you understood my issue and therefor would the ghusl be valid if I REALLY rinsed my nose 4th times unintentionally?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter how many times you rinse your nose as long as it is at least once, since that comes in the meaning of washing (ghusl).

Comment: I have read from several sources that you must not try to exceed rinsing your nose trice, but however I was unsure so I did it one more time to be sure so even though I rinsed my nose 4 times unintentionally. My ghusl will still be valid, yeah?